# An electron is an excitation of the electron field. So when we observe a higgs boson that means we've excited the higgs field?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, higgs

See this related question: [If particles are excitations what are their fields?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118927/if-particles-are-excitations-what-are-their-fields)

I ask this question because, according to a lecture, the higgs boson was frozen into a "matrix" at some point before recombination (otherwise we would not have atoms). Is this considered a field in the same way an electron field is a field? It was described that higgs was everywhere ... Is that another way of saying there is Higgs field?

This means the electron interacts with the higgs field and not with excitations of the higgs field? Or probably Higgs bosons are only excited momentarily.

Was the electron field also created like the higgs field at some point?

See here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hL2BLAOVbDA

Comment: Could you please provide a reference for the "frozen into a 'matrix'" statement?

Comment: Conceptually, there is no such thing as "the electron field". There is one field which can (conveniently) be broken down into different components for different simplified physical situations. All particles in the standard model originate from the same object, which, in a low energy approximation, has a few long lived components  like photons and the light leptons. It's only because of their lifetime, which happens to be "long" on our scale, that we can separate these particles easily in experiments. The latter is not true for quarks, any longer, which are confined to appear in pairs/triples.

Comment: @Frederic The use of the work matrix is unfortunate. But here's a link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hL2BLAOVbDA

Comment: @CuriousOne Not sure where this is coming from. Within the context of QFT that certainly does not seem to be the case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory

Comment: @yalis: I didn't write the wikipedia page and I can't take any responsibility for what has been written there. It is generally acknowledged, that the standard model is a low energy approximation of "something" that we simply don't understand, yet. That's physically perfectly admissible, since all of physics is about finding approximations. However, once we start discussing philosophical matters of "reality", then we better distinguish approximations (like the electron and photon "fields" mentioned in the wikipedia article) from reality, or the concepts break at the level of quarks, already.