# Constraints on creation operators operating on the electron field in order to produce a particle

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mathematical-physics

My background covers two years of QM, and I am now starting into QFT using Zee and Srednicki.

I am familiar with the math behind wave packets and their rapid dispersion, as one of the reasons they cannot represent particles. I have also covered QFT up to basic Feynman diagrams and the Dirac equation and the basic treatment of the fields as creation and annihilation operators.

My question is:

Can anybody describe, preferably in schematic terms if that's allowed here, (as I can study on this myself),  how a particle appears from the underlying field.

I am fully aware that a complete description is not appropriate here.

To put it another way, I am looking for a roadmap of the steps involved in taking  a field, for example the electron field, and getting a particle out of it.

I have searched for simple explanations and have come across the following:

[Excitations in the field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118927/if-particles-are-excitations-what-are-their-fields)

The second answer in the post includes:

> For the case of an electron, it is described by a Dirac spinor field $ψ$ with Lagrangian,
>
> $$L=ψ¯(iγμ∂μ−m)ψ$$
>
> We say the electron arises as an excitation of the quantum field $ψ$. On a technical level, if we expand the field using Fourier analysis, roughly like,
>
> $$\psi \sim \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \, \left( b_pe^{ipx}+c^\dagger_p e^{-ipx}\right)$$
>
> neglecting many factors.

I can follow the structure of this equation, but if this **is** the basic "wave", what constraints must it obey to create an electron?

Again schematically only,  if a quantum version of S.H.M is involved, I would like to know more. I think I read that a particle is connected with the smallest node, but I don't know if that makes sense to anyone.

Comment: Neither of those books will be able to explain you what you want to know. Rather, you will have to read Weinberg's books. Good luck!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thank you, (I think :) At least that explains why I couldn't find anything in them despite skipping ahead.

Comment: I don't think you can get out an electron out of a field or it makes sense.  First of all, all the fields are operators act on some state. and you can create or anhiliate a particle from that state, by simply applying those operators on that state. electron field is an operator that adds an electron to your state when applied to it.

Comment: @physshypp thank you for your comment, I will read up on the relationship between fields and states.